# Rails routing - :on => :collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, rails-routing

The [Rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) doesn't specify what `:on => :collection` means.

I cannot find an explanation to what the `:on` key is, nor what a `:collection` is in that context.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Routes on collections are listed [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-collection-routes).

The difference between `:on => :collection` and `:on => :member` are the style of route they produce and their associated route helpers.

```
resources :posts do
  # on collection
  get 'search', on: :collection 
  # --> generates '/posts/search' and search_posts_path

  # on member
  get 'share', on: :member      
  # --> generates'/posts/:id/share' and share_photo_path(@post)
end
```